# How to click or tap on a TextView text

Tags: android, onclick, listener, textview

I know this is so easy (doh...) but I am looking for a way to run a method on tapping or clicking a TextView line of text in an Android App.

I keep thinking about button listeners and anonymous method listener calls, but it just does not seem to apply to TextView.

Can someone point me at some code snippet to show how clicking or tapping on a piece of text in a TextView runs a method?

Comment: you should really accept the top-most answer.

Comment: He'd have to log in to do that.

Comment: And he has also taken away a nice username :/

Comment: For future, if somebody is using Kotlin and wants to have full control over the clickable text with callback - I wrote an article about it to have an extension function for `TextView` - https://link.medium.com/TLq6s8ltc3

Answer (score 474):

You can set the click handler in xml with these attribute:

```
android:onClick="onClick"
android:clickable="true"
```

Don't forget the clickable attribute, without it, the click handler isn't called.

main.xml

```
    ...

    <TextView 
       android:id="@+id/click"
       android:layout_width="wrap_content"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"               
       android:text="Click Me"
       android:textSize="55sp"
       android:onClick="onClick"                
       android:clickable="true"/>
    ...
```

MyActivity.java

```
       public class MyActivity extends Activity {

          public void onClick(View v) {
            ...
          }  
       }
```

Comment: "Don't forget the clickable attribute, without it, the click handler isn't called."  This line saved y day. Thanks a lot buddy.

Comment: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#attr_android:onClick needs to mention something about clickable. could have saved an hour.

Comment: funnily enough, using `setOnClickListener` sets the `clickable` attribute, but using the `onClick` attribute apparently does not.

Comment: It seems like `onClick` _does_ set the `clickable` attribute in Android 5.0 Lollipop (API 21). Maybe they considered it a bug that this didn't happen in older versions?

Comment: Is there a way to do this for long click via XML ?

Comment: I learned today that I didn't need to set clickable for regular app function, but for Espresso tests, I needed to set the clickable attribute to true or else my tests couldn't click the TextView.

Comment: It also seems like in addition, `enabled` needs to be `true` clickable to work

Comment: "Don't forget to make it public" would have been helpful too ^^ but thx

Comment: Also it's preferable to set `android:focusable = true` too

Answer (score 56):

This may not be quite what you are looking for but this is what worked for what I'm doing. All of this is after my `onCreate`:

```
boilingpointK = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.boilingpointK);

boilingpointK.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        if ("Boiling Point K".equals(boilingpointK.getText().toString()))
            boilingpointK.setText("2792");
        else if ("2792".equals(boilingpointK.getText().toString()))
            boilingpointK.setText("Boiling Point K");
    }
});
```

Answer (score 27):

OK I have answered my own question (but is it the best way?)

This is how to run a method when you click or tap on some text in a TextView:

```
package com.textviewy;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class TextyView extends Activity implements OnClickListener {

TextView t ;
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    t = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.TextView01);
    t.setOnClickListener(this);
}

public void onClick(View arg0) {
    t.setText("My text on click");  
    }
}
```

and my main.xml is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 android:orientation="vertical"
 android:layout_width="fill_parent"
 android:layout_height="fill_parent"
 >
<LinearLayout android:id="@+id/LinearLayout01" android:layout_width="wrap_content"             android:layout_height="wrap_content"></LinearLayout>
<ListView android:id="@+id/ListView01" android:layout_width="wrap_content"   android:layout_height="wrap_content"></ListView>
<LinearLayout android:id="@+id/LinearLayout02" android:layout_width="wrap_content"   android:layout_height="wrap_content"></LinearLayout>

<TextView android:text="This is my first text"
 android:id="@+id/TextView01" 
 android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
 android:textStyle="bold"
 android:textSize="28dip"
 android:editable = "true"
 android:clickable="true"
 android:layout_height="wrap_content">
 </TextView>
 </LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 13):

from inside an activity that calls a layout and a textview, this click listener works:

```
setContentView(R.layout.your_layout);
TextView tvGmail = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvGmail);
String TAG = "yourLogCatTag";
tvGmail.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View viewIn) {
                try {
                    Log.d(TAG,"GMAIL account selected");
                } catch (Exception except) {
                    Log.e(TAG,"Ooops GMAIL account selection problem "+except.getMessage());
                }
            }
        });
```

the text view is declared like this (default wizard):

```
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tvGmail"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/menu_id_google"
            android:textSize="30sp" />
```

and in the strings.xml file

```
<string name="menu_id_google">Google ID (Gmail)</string>
```

Answer (score 12):

Although you can resolve the problem by setting the listener to textview, it's recommended not to. You should use [flat button](http://www.google.com/design/spec/components/buttons.html#buttons-flat-raised-buttons) as it is a subclass of Button and it provides many attributes which TextView doesn't.

---

To use flat button, add `style="?android:attr/borderlessButtonStyle"` attribute -

```
<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="DONE"
    style="?android:attr/borderlessButtonStyle"/>
```

Comment: You also might want to add `android:textAllCaps="false"` to allow for lower case texts.

Answer (score 9):

in textView

```
<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="New Text"
    android:onClick="onClick"
    android:clickable="true"
```

You must also implement View.OnClickListener and in On Click method can use intent

```
    Intent intent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
           intent.setData(Uri.parse("https://youraddress.com"));    
            startActivity(intent);
```

I tested this solution works fine.

Answer (score 4):

To click on a piece of the text (not the whole `TextView`), you can use `Html` or `Linkify` (both create links that open urls, though, not a callback in the app).

### `Linkify`

Use a string resource like:

```
<string name="links">Here is a link: http://www.stackoverflow.com</string>
```

Then in a textview:

```
TextView textView = ...
textView.setText(R.string.links);
Linkify.addLinks(textView, Linkify.ALL);
```

### `Html`

Using `Html.fromHtml`:

```
<string name="html">Here you can put html &lt;a href="http://www.stackoverflow.com"&gt;Link!&lt;/&gt;</string>
```

Then in your textview:

```
textView.setText(Html.fromHtml(getString(R.string.html)));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use TextWatcher for TextView, is more flexible than ClickLinstener (not best or worse, only more one way).

```
holder.bt_foo_ex.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
            // code during!

        }

        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {
            // code before!

        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
            // code after!

        }
    });
```