# how to make text view clickable in android?

Tags: android

is it possible in android to  make text view clickable if yes then how ??and if not then what will  be the way for make a label clickable??i want to implement a call activity using this

```
private void call() {
     try {
         Intent callIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL);
         callIntent.setData(Uri.parse("tel:"+keywordxmlparsing.phone));
         startActivity(callIntent);
     } catch (ActivityNotFoundException activityException) {
         Log.e("dialing-example", "Call failed", activityException);
     }
 }
```

thanks  for ur responses in advance...

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to click or tap on a TextView text](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3328757/how-to-click-or-tap-on-a-textview-text)

Answer (score 52, accepted):

```
textView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener());
```

Have you tried this?

Answer (score 18):

More easier directly in the XML : with clickable = true

```
<TextView
                android:id="@+id/forgotPassword"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:text="@string/forgotPassword"
                android:onClick="forgotPassword"
                android:clickable="true"
                />
```

Comment: Can you do a "long click" with XML as well?

Answer (score 12):

We can also get click event on `TextView` same as `Button` & `ImageView`.

and method is also same for all View.

like as

```
view.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }
        });
```

Answer (score 6):

First in your java file cast your `TextView` by xml id

```
TextView tv = (TextView)findViewById(R.Id.textView1);
```

then,

```
tv.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
   @Override
   public void onClick(View v) {
      // TODO Auto-generated method stub
   }
});
```

Answer (score 6):

Honestly, I found a flat button to work better for what I was doing with a RecyclerView:

```
<Button
android:id="@+id/btnFoo"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
style="?android:attr/borderlessButtonStyle"/>
```

Source: https://stackoverflow.com/a/30884132/2328637

Then customizing the button to fit my layout and finally adding the following to my MainActivity.java under `onCreate`:

```
Button btnFoo = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnFoo);
btnFoo.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

   @Override
   public void onClick(View v) {
      Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, FooActivity.class);
      startActivity(intent);
   }
});
```

Comment: This is what I was looking for. Thanks :)

Answer (score 4):

Try this:

```
view.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {

    }
});
```

Answer (score 4):

In the xml for that TextView include the field

```
android:onClick="functionName"
```

Then in your java file associated with that xml include this function

```
public void functionName(View view){
// do your stuff
}
```

Answer (score 2):

you can set a onclick listener to the texview like button.infact button inherits the properties from textview.

Answer (score 0):

Though it was long ago when you asked your question. But I think that the right thing to attain what you wanted is to set TextView xml attribute android:autoLink. For example:

```
<TextView 
    ...
    android:autoLink="phone" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply try this one:-

Implement View.OnClickListener, then simply apply switch case and define the id of your text view in the case and pass the intent.

example:-

```
     @Override
 public void onClick(View v) {
    //TODO Auto-generated method stub

   switch (v.getId()) {
case R.id.textView:
    startActivity(new Intent(this,CalledClass.class));

    break;

default:
    break;
}
```

//here textView is id for the textView I chose.

Answer (score 0):

TextView is also derived of View like- EditText,ListView etc.,so we can use

```
textView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener());
```