# In Android Studio why is there no TextViewPreference?

Tags: java, android, android-studio

Ok so I wanted to create a Settings activity. I was told using the Preference layout makes it much easier.
I want a TextView that when clicked does a certain action, yet there is no TextViewPreference. The closest thing is EditTextPreference that must have the attribute "selectable" set to off which turns it gray.

Also another thing, these Preferences have no ID attribute. How am I supposed to attach OnClickListeners to them if they have no ID???

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6226699

Comment: what functionality you want exactly....?your question is unclear...did you got solution what @Doc has given link?

Comment: @Wini I just want to be able to place a TextView in the Preference Screen layout

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try-->

***Method 1***

**create a custom preference layout item and use it in the Preference Activity:-**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:minHeight="?android:attr/listPreferredItemHeight"
android:gravity="center_vertical"
android:paddingRight="?android:attr/scrollbarSize">

    <TextView android:id="@android:id/title"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:ellipsize="marquee"
        android:fadingEdge="horizontal" />

  </LinearLayout>
```

**add in preference xml:**

```
<Preference
android:title="@string/label_pref_version"
android:key="@string/pref_version"
android:layout="@layout/pref" />
```

**then lastly:-**

fire `findViewById` in your Activity code and attach a listener....

***Method 2***

**For the xml:**

```
<Preference android:title="Acts like a text"
            android:key="@string/myCooltext"
            android:summary="This is a text"/>
```

**Then for the java in your onCreate()**

```
Preference text = findPreference(getString(R.string.myCoolText));
text.setOnPreferenceClickListener(new Preference.OnPreferenceClickListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onPreferenceClick(Preference preference) {   
                //code for what you want it to do   
                return true;
            }
        });
```

***Method 3***

You can try it like this to get the Textview in activity:

```
 View name= ((LayoutInflater) this.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE)).inflate(R.layout.layouttext, null, false);
```

add android:id to the `LinearLayout` that contains the `Textview` in layouttext.xml, i.e. android:id="@+id/mylayout"

```
 LinearLayout mLayout = (LinearLayout)name.findViewById(R.id.mylayout);
  Textview login = (Textview) footerView.findViewById(R.id.Text);
  login.setOnClickListener(this);
```

Comment: Hi. With method 2 I can't find a findPreference() method

Comment: you are extending to what ? `PreferenceFragment` or `PreferenceActivity` ?????\

Comment: The second. btw what is boolean for in public boolean onPreferenceClick(Preference preference)?

Comment: Called when a Preference has been clicked.....True if the click was handled.....

Comment: What happens if it returns false?

Comment: If you do not handle the click i.e. you don't do anything when this is clicked --> returning false

Comment: Is there a way other than findPreference to get a reference to a preference? I mean a way inside AppCompatActivity

Comment: no there is no way through AppCompactactvity...you need you extend or implement using `PreferenceFragmentCompat`  or `PrefernceActivity` or `PreferneceFragment`

Comment: Sorry. I tried both methods. Neither worked for various reasons. If there is a complete working example of findPreference can you post it? It's inside a static class which makes working with it impossible.

Comment: added 3rd method...try this tooo