# How to make a part of text clickable like button in Android?

Tags: android, button, click, textview

I would like to add button myButton to TextView. How to get it in a single line so that it looks like one set of lines. Here is sample of the text to be added

**Please press this here to refresh the set of values.**

I want to have "here" as clickable button. How can I do it. Any snippet on it would be helpful.

Comment: duplicate question:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3328757/how-to-click-or-tap-on-a-textview-text

Comment: You can try some of these approaches:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1697084/handle-textview-link-click-in-my-android-app

Answer (score 3, accepted):

make three textView ex: textView1, textView2 and textView3.

```
<RelativeLayout android:id="@+id/textLay"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    >

    <TextView android:id="@+id/textView1" android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:text="Please press this"/>

    <TextView android:id="@+id/textView2" android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
         android:text="here" 
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/textView1"  />

    <TextView android:id="@+id/textView3" android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
         android:text="to refresh the set of values." 
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/textView2"  />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: This doesnt comes well when we take into multi line text.How to solve it in due with modifying the snippet.

Answer (score 14):

Set background of `Button` as null by `android:background="@null"` give the same text color as given to other `TextView`'s.

or You can take 3 TextView's and `setOnClickListener` to middle one.

Comment: how to have three textviews followed by one another in a multi line

Comment: Hey ur suggestion was very useful to me...thanx

Comment: Simple and Elegant!
I needed the link text color to be same as default color of hyperlinks in web. So I put `RGB(0, 122, 255)`, and looks the same! (Y)

Answer (score 12):

Set style of `Button` with borderless android attribut to remove background and border:

```
<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    style="?android:attr/borderlessButtonStyle"
    android:text="here" />
```

Answer (score 3):

Just add below attribute to TextView in XML layout file to make it clickable.

```
android:clickable="true"
```

In your Java file add **OnClickListener** to complete click action on text view.

Answer (score 2):

Add `android:clickable="true"` and `android:onClick="yourclickname"` for the `TextView` in the XML. Then define `yourclickname` in your activity. This should make your `TextView` clickable and triggers the specified method when clicked.

Comment: easiest solution and answers the original question exactly.