# Using TextView's onClick to go to the next page

Tags: android, android-layout, android-intent, android-emulator

For a better UI, I thought of using TextViews in place of Buttons. When a TextView is clicked, the next page of the application should appear. I have defined onClick functions in the XML file, but it's not working.

Here is the XML file.

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
    android:onClick="serve"
    android:text="@string/Service"
    android:textSize="20dp" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_marginTop="87dp"
    android:onClick="complain"
    android:text="@string/Comp"
    android:textSize="20dp" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView3"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textView2"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textView2"
    android:layout_marginTop="121dp"
    android:onClick="feed"
    android:text="@string/Feedback"
    android:textSize="20dp" />
```

Java file:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    public void serve(View v)
    {
        Intent i=new Intent();
        i.setClass(this,Second.class);
        startActivity(i);
    }

    public void complain(View v)
    {
        Intent in=new Intent();
        in.setClass(this,Third.class);
        startActivity(in);
    }

    public void feed(View v)
    {
        Intent inn=new Intent();
        inn.setClass(this,Fourth.class);
        startActivity(inn);
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes, but what do you want to display on "the next page"? Where is this code?

Comment: thats the secondary thing...what matters is this xml file n even the d java file... I have used appropriate functions like serve, complain and feed in the java file..onClick will go to these java files :)

Comment: Can you be more specific? Not working doesn't tell me much. Is it throwing an error or not responding to touch events or...

Comment: i get all the textviews on the screen but they are not responding to the touch. it doesnt show any error...

Comment: See my answer... Don't see any code in your activity that tells the textViews to respond to touch events.

Comment: @bytebender yeah but how it will understand which page it has to go to?? like nothing is mentioned in the code about the next java file..

Comment: @bytebender yeah my bad...am sorry...anyway thanks :) i used sam's method n it worked :) thanks a lot for ur help too:)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

A TextView is not clickable by default so the onClick action can never be called... Simply add: `android:clickable="true"` to each of your TextViews:

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:onClick="serve"
    android:text="@string/Service"
    android:textSize="20dp" />
```

Buttons and many other Views expect user interaction so they are already clickable, but not a TextView.

---

Also since your onClick() methods perform the same basic action, consider a generic method instead:

```
public void click(View v) {
    Intent intent;
    switch(v.getId()) {
    case R.id.serve: // R.id.textView1
        intent = new Intent(this, Second.class);
        break;
    case R.id.complain: // R.id.textView2
        intent = new Intent(this, Third.class);
        break;
    case R.id.feed: // R.id.textView3
        intent = new Intent();
    }
    startActivity(intent);
}
```

You need to modify your `id` and `onClick` attributes in each TextView, like so:

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/serve"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:onClick="click"
    android:text="@string/Service"
    android:textSize="20dp" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have the following methods (with matching signatures) in your Activity. They should each take a parameter that is a `View`.

```
public void serve(View v) { }
public void complain(View v) { }
public void feed(View v) { }
```

Answer (score 0):

Your activity (based on your code doesn't have any `onClickListeners()` You need to obtain a reference to your textViews and then add an event handler and then inside your event handler is where you would call `serve(), complain(), feed()` See this SO [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3328757/how-to-click-or-tap-on-a-textview-text).  Here is an example of changes in your activity class.

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    TextView textView1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.TextView1);
    textView1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        protected void onClick(View view) {

            serve(view);
        }

    });

    //Repeat for each text view...
}
```

Each TextView will have to have the following to attributes set in xml:

```
android:onClick="onClick"
android:clickable="true"
```

**Edit:**

I still don't see where you Activity **implements OnclickListener** if you are going to do it that way...

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements OnclickListener {


    protected void onClick(View view) {
        // borrowed from @Sam
        Intent intent;

        switch(v.getId()) {
            case R.id.serve: // R.id.textView1
                intent = new Intent(this, Second.class);
                break;
            case R.id.complain: // R.id.textView2
                intent = new Intent(this, Third.class);
                break;
            case R.id.feed: // R.id.textView3
                intent = new Intent();
            }

            startActivity(intent);
    }

}
```

Comment: The OP's `OnClickListeners` are called `serve`, `complain` and `feed` and are clearly present in the code posted in the question. The issue is purely that `TextView` isn't clickable by default - Sam already answered that.

Comment: need not use intent??public void serve(View v)
{
    Intent i=new Intent();
    i.setClass(this,Second.class);
    startActivity(i);

}

Comment: @Shreya : All that should be needed is to add `android:clickable="true"` to your `TextViews` and your existing code should work. Sam already answered that in his answer.