# how to click on textview in android

Tags: android, xml, android-widget, textview

Click on text view is not working

My xml is

```
<TextView
android:id="@+id/button2"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
android:layout_weight="3"
android:gravity="center" 
android:textColor="@color/white"
android:text="click to download sevenstepstocollege"
android:textSize="15dp"
android:onClick="downloadLink"
android:clickable="true">
</TextView>
```

and My Activity code is

```
public void downloadLink(View v)
{
//String requestId = PurchasingManager.initiatePurchaseRequest(skuKye);
//String requestId=PurchasingManager.initiateItemDataRequest("DeveloperSKU-1234");
skuSet.add(skuKye);
final String requestId = PurchasingManager.initiateItemDataRequest(skuSet);
}
```

But it is not working.I am not able to click that link.please guide me

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3328757/how-to-click-or-tap-on-a-textview-text

Comment: I am using a amazone apps with my current apps. In the textview the text is "click here to go to seven easy steps"

Comment: post all your java code where you declare the downloadLink() function please !

Comment: i am using the same page but it is not working :(

Comment: How can i post the code here in comment??

Comment: String skuKye="DeveloperSKU-1234";
final Set<String> skuSet = new HashSet<String>();               public void downloadLink(View v) {
  //String requestId = PurchasingManager.initiatePurchaseRequest(skuKye);
  //String requestId=PurchasingManager.initiateItemDataRequest("DeveloperSKU-1234");
  skuSet.add(skuKye);
  final String requestId = PurchasingManager.initiateItemDataRequest(skuSet);
  
 }

 private OnClickListener purchaseClickListener = new OnClickListener()
 {
   
  public void onClick(View v) {
   final String requestId = PurchasingManager.initiateItemDataRequest(skuSet);
 }
 };

Comment: android:onClick is for API level 4 onwards, so if you're targeting < 1.6, then you can't use it.

Answer (score 2):

Well, I use the following code to make a TextView clickable.

First, add this at your activity.xml, to make TextView clikable:

> ```
> <TextView
>     android:id=android:id="@+id/button2" <!-- id to get this TextView -->
>     (...)
>     android:onClick="onClick"  <!-- Add the function onClick() -->
>     android:clickable="true"   <!-- Set the boolean clickable to true -->
> />
> ```

Then, at your MainActivity.java, you add:

```
private TextView textview;    

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);    
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);  

    // Get the TextView by id
    textview = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.button2);

    textview.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
              // TODO when clicked on your link(TextView)
        }
    });
}
```

As I see now that you are trying to make a link from the TextView clickable, not just be able to click on the TextView I will let a link below to a similar question solved in Stack Overflow that you might find helpful.

The android developer reference to TextView:
https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html

The similar question in Stack Overflow about how to make a links in a clickable that might be helpful:
[How do I make links in a TextView clickable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2734270/how-do-i-make-links-in-a-textview-clickable#2746708)

Answer (score 1):

You may use like this

```
<TextView
                            android:id="@+id/topPaid"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:autoLink="all"
                            android:clickable="true"                           
                            android:text="@string/topPaid"
                            android:textColor="#000000"
                            android:textColorLink="#33CC33" />
```

and At activity

```
TextView topPaid = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.topPaid);

Linkify.addLinks(topPaid, Linkify.ALL);

topPaid.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {

//write ur logic
}
}
```

Comment: Linkify.addLinks(topPaid, Linkify.ALL);
  topPaid.setMovementMethod(LinkMovementMethod.getInstance());
  // t1.setClickable(true);
  topPaid.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {  //ur logic}

  });

Answer (score 0):

```
TextView textview = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.text);
textview.setText(Html.fromHtml("<b>Text:</b>  Text with a " + "<a href=\"http://www.google.com\">link</a> " + "Created in the Java source code using HTML."));
```

Comment: i am not using the direct redirecting the website because i am using a amazone apps with my apps and i done the coding of that part..but the problem is that i am not able to click on the button

Comment: i call the amazone api for buying the book from the user

Comment: i have a textview and whenever i click on that textview i call the amazone apps which is integrated with my apps and the person who is using this apps he has a option to buy the book directly no need to go to amezone website directly.

Comment: i have this code in xml. <TextView
                     android:id="@+id/button2"
                     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                     android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                     android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                     android:layout_weight="3"
                     android:gravity="center" 
                     android:textColor="@color/white"
                     android:text="click to download sevenstepstocollege"
                     android:textSize="15dp" >

                </TextView>

Comment: and i have to call this method public void downloadLink(View v) {
  //String requestId = PurchasingManager.initiatePurchaseRequest(skuKye);
  //String requestId=PurchasingManager.initiateItemDataRequest("DeveloperSKU-1234");
  skuSet.add(skuKye);
  final String requestId = PurchasingManager.initiateItemDataRequest(skuSet); 
 }

Comment: i put the xml code and i have a method in java class.how to call the method with the clicking the textview in xml file

Answer (score 0):

XML Code

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
```

JAVA Code

```
    TextView textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
    textView.setText(Html.fromHtml("<a href=\"http://www.google.com\">google</a> "));
    textView.setMovementMethod(LinkMovementMethod.getInstance());
```

Comment: yes i do that but it is direct goes to the website but i am not using the direct redirecting the website because i am using a amazone apps with my apps and i done the coding of that part..but the problem is that i am not able to click on the button

Comment: i cannot understand what u want to do with textview. so please add ur code for better understanding

Comment: i have a textview and whenever i click on that textview i call the amazone apps which is integrated with my apps and the person who is using this apps he has a option to buy the book directly no need to go to amezone website directly.

Comment: // u can try this
  TextView textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
  textView.setText(Html.fromHtml("<a href=\"http://www.google.com\">google</a> "));
  Linkify.addLinks(textView, Linkify.ALL);
  textView.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
   
   public void onClick(View v) {
    //ur code
   }
  });

Answer (score 0):

In your XML as the following:

```
 <TextView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:onClick="onTextViewPressed"
   />
```

In your attached activity
public void onTextViewPressed(View view) {
...
}