# How to make some text clickable in android?

Tags: android, user-interface, textview

You must have seen in various apps on their login screens after login button there is a line stating "Don't Have an Account? Sign Up" and here Sign up is a link which on clicking takes us to sign up screen(not to a website or something). I want to do the same.

Thank You!

Comment: Have a look at [how-to-ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Also, have a detailed look at [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3328757/how-to-click-or-tap-on-a-textview-text

Answer (score 1):

Example:

```
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Sign Up"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:onClick="clickHandler"/>
```

And in your activity, define the `clickHandler()` method in your `Activity` like so:

```
public void clickHandler(View view) {
    // your code
}
```