# Wanting to throw an intent to open a new activity but continually crashes

Tags: java, android, android-intent

There's nothing fancy or complicated here. I am just looking to open a new, blank, activity from when I press on the textview. From the projects completed files, I seem to have done it as it wants me to. However, every time I click on the textview to start the intent to open the other activity, it crashes. I cannot seem to find the cause either. In a separate app I've made that send a text string from an edit text field via a button, seems to work fine and that has some other more detailed code to perform that, so I am not entirely sure where the error is arising here.

## MainActivity.java

```
package com.example.android.miwok;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.view.View;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    // Set the content of the activity to use the activity_main.xml layout file
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
 }

public void openNumbersList(View view) {
    Intent i = new Intent(this, NumbersActivity.class);
    startActivity(i);
 }
}
```

## NumbersActivity.java

```
package com.example.android.miwok;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class NumbersActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_numbers);

 }
}
```

## activity_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@color/tan_background"
android:orientation="vertical"
tools:context="com.example.android.miwok.MainActivity">

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/numbers"
    style="@style/CategoryStyle"
    android:background="@color/category_numbers"
    android:onClick="openNumbersList"
    android:text="@string/category_numbers" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/family"
    style="@style/CategoryStyle"
    android:background="@color/category_family"
    android:text="@string/category_family" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/colors"
    style="@style/CategoryStyle"
    android:background="@color/category_colors"
    android:text="@string/category_colors" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/phrases"
    style="@style/CategoryStyle"
    android:background="@color/category_phrases"
    android:text="@string/category_phrases" />

</LinearLayout>
```

In logcat there's an error showing when the app crashes:

02-20 20:10:26.762 7582-7582/com.example.android.miwok E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                         Process: com.example.android.miwok, PID: 7582
                                                                         java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.android.miwok/com.example.android.miwok.NumbersActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #0: Binary XML file line #0: Error inflating class TextView

Comment: Post the complete stacktrace (formatted as a code block) and the `activity_numbers.xml` file

Comment: add `android:height` `android:width` to all of your text view

Comment: Please post the content of file: activity_numbers.xml

Comment: The intent is not the problem. The XML in the next activity is. Specifically the TextViews

Comment: remove the style attribute from TextViews and let us know the result

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"Error inflating class TextView" means that your xml in the next activity is faulty. Try removing all the views from the 2nd activity's layout, double check the layout and then try it. If it is just the intent launch you wanna confirm, this should work.

Comment: Very nice sir, as you stated, my xml in the new activity was incorrect. I had android:textSize="?android:textAppearanceLarge"

Answer (score 2):

In your xml layout for the Text view with id numbers add

```
android:clickable="true"
```

Only if this attribute is set to true the text view's onclick handler will be called

And also add height and width to all your textviews.. like this

```
android:height="wrap_content"
android:width="wrap_content"
```

This must have caused the app crash

There is a post on how to set click listeners to textviews [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3328757/how-to-click-or-tap-on-a-textview-text) .

Comment: Not having this set won't cause it to crash when clicking on it

Comment: I did add this before the verified fix to see if it was correct or caused the crash, and it was not. I just added the two android attributes clickable and then focusable (focusable after testing *just* clickable and it crashing still).

Upon fixing my xml and verifying it worked, I removed these and it still works fine.